# My website is not working on safari iOS NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, mobile-safari

I am hosting my website using a VPS and Nginx.

Everything works properly everywher BUT on iOS... when I try to access my website, safari tells me `"Safari can’t establish a secure connection"`

I can't get it, my SSL certificates are working everywhere but on safari..

Here's my nginx config :

```
server {
  server_name louislecouturier.fr www.louislecouturier.fr;

  location / {
    # this must stay localhost. The port must be the same as your Next.js project
    proxy_pass http://$server_addr:3000;
  }

  # simple headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY always;

  # this will serve the project on port 80

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/louislecouturier.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/louislecouturier.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {

  server_name api.louislecouturier.fr www.api.louislecouturier.fr;

  location / {

    proxy_pass http://$server_addr:1337;

  }

  # simple headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY always;

  # this will serve the project on port 80

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/louislecouturier.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/louislecouturier.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.louislecouturier.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = louislecouturier.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name louislecouturier.fr www.louislecouturier.fr;
  listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = api.louislecouturier.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  server_name api.louislecouturier.fr www.api.louislecouturier.fr;
  listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

My SSL certificates were generated by certbot.
You can access my website at https://louislecouturier.fr

I've read some protocol conflicts with http2 could create errors on safari iOS but I haven't manually configured my server to use it (maybe it is by default ?)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hey! Got the same problem. Did you find out? I have checked your website and it works on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Turns out I just had to add the ipV6 listener on each servers

```
listen [::]:80;
```

```
listen [::]:443;
```